# Illuminated Mirror Wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, light, mirror

I've purchased an illuminated mirror (with a built in light strip around the outside) for my bathroom remodel. I'm trying to figure out the best way to wire it.

I have the wiring prepped for a new outlet in the wall behind the mirror. The back of the mirror is flat, and sits flush against the wall. The electric connection for the mirror is a wire with un-terminated ends. The instructions provided for wiring are below:

[image]

Options I'm considering:

1. Based on the instructions, in appears the suggestion is similar to a ceiling fan or light fixture, wire-nut the wires to the mains connection, stuff it inside a wall-box, and conceal with the mirror. Will this satisfy code? Is there a faceplate I should be using with the wall-box?
2. Install a recessed outlet, terminate the mirror wires in the flattest grounded plug I can find, and hope the plug isn't proud of the wall so the mirror can sit flush

Or any other suggestions?

Comment: I like option 2. Shop for "single gang recessed single receptacle".

Comment: Thanks. I took a closer look, the backing of the mirror does has some flex to it. So even with a slightly protruding plug, I think the mirror could fit flush against the wall.

Answer (score 2):

I would double check the manufacturer instructions they may state the mirror is the cover just like a light fixture when mounted. A cover plat makes a slight bulge and could crack the mirror depending on how it mounts.

Comment: Here are the instructions. They're pretty light on details unfortunately. The relevant section is basically " Match & attach 3 electrical wires from mirror to home electrical wires: Live to Live, Ground to Ground, Neutral to Neutral." https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0756/5369/files/GALAXY_48x36.pdf

Comment: Well there is a driver supplying power to the fixture is this located in the box I can't tell from the instructions, a call to the mfg to make sure I would think the mirror would be the same as a light fixture because the box is covered by the mirror. If a cover with a grommet was required it would be specified so at this point I would think the mirror would be the same as a light fixture.